# Play video upon a Fragment but below Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to write a simple code to play video form raw folder and I have to play video on fragment but my activity has a navigation drawer so when I have tried to play this video at first time there is only voice no video so I search for this problem then I got a solution  `videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true)` but now there is another issue I faced that is the video window comes upon the navigation drawer.this is the screen shot what is happing

[image]

hear is my xml layouts
This is for activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    style="@style/textDisply2.title"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_call_sleep_care"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@color/buttonColor"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/column_padding"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/call_care_small"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/home_wh_btn_txt"
        android:text="@string/call_sleep_care" />

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and This is my fragment layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/screen_name"
        android:text="@string/video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/screen_name"
        android:id="@+id/video_dis_box"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play_video_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/img_btn_height_play"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/img_btn_width_play"
            android:src="@mipmap/music"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="@dimen/column_padding"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_title"
                android:text="@string/video_title"
                style="@style/textDisply2.subHead"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dr_surendra"
                android:text="@string/dr_surendra"
                style="@style/textDisply2.subHead"
                android:textSize="@dimen/home_color_btn_txt"

                />

        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lock"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/img_btn_height_lock"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/img_btn_width_lock"
            android:src="@mipmap/lock"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

        <VideoView
            android:layout_below="@+id/video_dis_box"
            android:id="@+id/play_video"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Please post your xml layout.

Comment: Thanks for response hata I have add xmls please check

Answer (score 0):

I think that to invoke `videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true)` is non-sense.

What I think you have better to do is to close the Navigation Drawer.

So somewhere in your code for example:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(drawer_layout);
NavigationView navigationView = (NavagationView) findViewById(nav_view);
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView);
```

will close the Drawer and the VideoView won't be hidden.

Note: the code to close the Drawer may differ depends on your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion hata But it's not working no effect

Comment: I find my mistake I set background colour at App style when I remove this and videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true) video work's fine on fragment and show below navigation drawer Thanks for help hata.